# Worklight JSONStore - under what upgrade scenarios would it be permanently lost?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

<strike>As I understand it, a Worklight JSONStore is only available to hybrid Worklight applications.</strike>

**Correction**: A Worklight JSONStore is available to both hybrid and native applications as of Worklight 6.2. My mistake.

For either type of application, under what application upgrade circumstances would the data in it be permanently lost? For example, I see at least three variations of upgrade:

1. **Upgrade using Direct Update** - I would assume the contents of the JSONStore will be kept as-is in these circumstances.
2. **Complete deletion of the application followed by installation of the new version** - I would assume the content of the JSONStore would be completely lost in these circumstances.
3. **Binary upgrade of the application from AppCenter / App Store / Play Store / MDM solution / etc.** - In this case, will the JSONStore continue to exist between one version and the next with the same data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight JSONStore is available for Hybrid applications and also for Native applications (starting Worklight 6.2).

Per [the JSONStore documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html?lang=en):

> *Reliable Storage* means that your data is not deleted unless one of the
>   following events occurs:
>
> - The application is removed from the device.
> - One of the methods that removes data is called.

To cover your mentioned cases:

1. Direct Update: JSONStore data remains as-is (unless your update triggers code that will cause code deletion...)
2. Deletion of application: this will remove the application and any associated data, including JSONStore
3. Application update: this will not remove the JSONStore

Comment: so you are saying that a binary upgrade of the .apk/.ipa doesn't count as removing the application, for these purposes?